# Multiple values for same session variable in jsp

Tags: jsp, session

My code generates a table, for every row an update and delete buttons are generated. When either update or delete buttons are pressed the relative row's number is supposed to be saved as a session variable but instead only the last row's number is saved. this method works in php though. I tried to assign session variables though the "onclick"attribute in html but it does not work either.I understand why and am trying to figure out a way around it.

```
    <%
            while(result.next()){
    %>
        <tr>
            <td><%out.print("<p>"+result.getInt(1)+"</p>"); %></td>
            <td><%out.print("<p>"+result.getString(2)+"</p>"); %></td>
            <td><%out.print("<p>"+result.getString(3)+"</p>"); %></td>
            <td><%out.print("<p>"+result.getString(4)+"</p>"); %></td>
            <td><%out.print("<p>"+result.getString(5)+"</p>"); %></td>
            <td><%out.print("<p>"+result.getInt(6)+"</p>"); %></td>
            <td>
                <form action="DeleteUserServlet" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" 
                onclick="<%session.setAttribute("id",result.getInt(1));%>">
                </form>                     
                <form action="UpdateUser.jsp" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" onclick="
                <%session.setAttribute("id",result.getInt(1));%>">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
```

Comment: *update and delete button is generated

Comment: Why don't you do that in your DeleteUserServlet ?

Comment: That is what i want to do, my problem is when i click an update or delete button the session variable will not be set to its respective id number, it will get set to the last id number. Therefore no matter what row's delete button i select it will delete the last row.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I found a solution, thanx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do this by setting the session variable you need to use a hidden input in the form.

```
<%
while(result.next())
{
%>
<tr>
    <td><% out.print("<p>"+result.getInt(1)+"</p>"); %></td>
    <td><% out.print("<p>"+result.getString(2)+"</p>"); %></td>
    <td><% out.print("<p>"+result.getString(3)+"</p>"); %></td>
    <td><% out.print("<p>"+result.getString(4)+"</p>"); %></td>
    <td><% out.print("<p>"+result.getString(5)+"</p>"); %></td>
    <td><% out.print("<p>"+result.getInt(6)+"</p>"); %></td>
    <td>
    <form action="DeleteUserServlet" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<% out.print(result.getInt(1)); %>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>                     
    <form action="UpdateUser.jsp" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<% out.print(result.getInt(1)); %>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
```

Why does what you were doing not work? All the Java code runs on the server-side, so even when you put something like `<input type="submit" value="Update" onclick="<%session.setAttribute("id",result.getInt(1));%>">` that Java code setting the session attribute runs before the HTML page is sent to the browser, not when the user clicks that button. So what your code was actually doing was setting the session attribute over an over in a loop, and the resulting HTML going to the client was having the onClick value blank: `<input type="submit" value="Update" onclick="">`

Comment: Because when the jsp file gets processed it is converted to a servlet, I think and the code runs from top to bottom so no matter what values i set for the variable it gets the value of the last assignment. no matter i found another way, i can send the id through the url and capture it by the doGet. Thank you for all your help people :D

Comment: @ruvinda Although you could do that, for deleting/updating its certainly better to use POST.